# Bokeh: How to handle cliking on text in Div?

Tags: javascript, python, html, bokeh

I have a bokeh server application.
I have one text Div element with some words.

If I click on one of them, I want to trigger an action (draw a chart), let's say.
I can add a hyperlink so the content of the Div would be

---

```
<a href="something">abc</a>
<a href="somethingElse">defgh</a>
```

---

**How can I call a callback python/bokeh function from there?**

Answer (score 0):

Python is a server-side language.
You cannot write directly server-side language in JS (dynamics things like reacting to a click without page reload is done with javascript), what you can do is to call the server to ask it to draw your chart, then add the html returned by the server to your DOM. (There are others way to do this, you could go to another page where the graph is drawed, but the question has been tagged with "javascript").
For example:

```
<a href="something">abc</a> <a href="somethingElse">defgh</a>
<div id="mygraph"></div>
<script>
// Here you bind an event on <a href="something">abc</a>
document.querySelector('a[href="something"]')
   .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // Here you create a request
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('GET', "http://my-url-which-display-my-graph.dev");
       xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
       // This callback is called when the request's state change
           if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
           // You enter in this condition if the request is done and successfull

               document.getElementById('mygraph').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
           }
    });
});
xhr.send();
</script>
```

This code has not been tested, it has been provided as an example.

For bokeh, it seems as you have a client side library:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html

(I do not know bokeh but I will try to answer):

```
<a href="something">abc</a> <a href="somethingElse">defgh</a>
<div id="mygraph"></div>
<script>
// Here you bind an event on <a href="something">abc</a>
document.querySelector('a[href="something"]')
   .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // My bokeh code, from their doc:
       var x = Bokeh.LinAlg.linspace(-0.5, 20.5, 10);
       var y = x.map(function (v) { return v * 0.5 + 3.0; });
       var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({ data: { x: x, y: y } });

       // create some ranges for the plot
       var xdr = new Bokeh.Range1d({ start: -0.5, end: 20.5 });
       var ydr = Bokeh.Range1d(-0.5, 20.5);

       // make the plot
       var plot = new Bokeh.Plot({
          title: "BokehJS Plot",
          x_range: xdr,
          y_range: ydr,
          plot_width: 400,
          plot_height: 400,
          background_fill_color: "#F2F2F7"
       });
       var xaxis = new Bokeh.LinearAxis({ axis_line_color: null });
       var yaxis = new Bokeh.LinearAxis({ axis_line_color: null });
       plot.add_layout(xaxis, "below");
       plot.add_layout(yaxis, "left");

       var line = new Bokeh.Line({
           x: { field: "x" },
           y: { field: "y" },
           line_color: "#666699",
           line_width: 2
        });
       plot.add_glyph(line, source);

       // add the plot to a document and display it
       var doc = new Bokeh.Document();
       doc.add_root(plot);
       document.getElementById("mygraph").innerHTML = "";
       Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone(doc, document.getElementById("mygraph"));
</script>
```

This code has not been tested, it has been provided as an example.

There are many ways to do this, you could draw the chart first and then hide it / show it using JS + CSS. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.
If you do not want to use the client-side library, you can redirect the user to another page where the chart is drawed.

If you are new to javascript, I would recommend to use a library like jQuery to have an easy way to do things.